# angular2-jwt token alwas not valid

Tags: angular, jwt

So I have a simple angular 2/laravel app wit jwt authentification support. I have a service that verifies everytime a route is called if the jwt token is valid or not using the angular2-jwt tokenNotExpired() function, but this function always return false for a reason, so the user would be always redirected to login page.

So it goes like that the user logs in, a token will be generated from the backend and saved on local storage, than a service will check if the token is valid before initiating any route using the CanActivate lifecycle hook.

Here is what i did so far:

Login Component:

```
   ...
            this.http.post(SERVER_URL + 'auth', body, {
                headers: headers
            }
            ).subscribe(
                data => {

                    localStorage.setItem('auth_token', data.json().token);
                    this.authHttp.get(SERVER_URL + 'auth/user', headers)
                        .subscribe(
                        data => {
                            this.store.dispatch({ type: SET_CURRENT_USER_PROFILE, payload: data.json().user });
                            localStorage.setItem('user', data.json().user);
                            this.router.navigate(['/home']);

                        },
                        err => console.log('Fehlermeldung: ' + err)
                        );

                },
...
```

app.module :

```
...
 { provide: AuthConfig, useValue: new AuthConfig({
              headerName: 'Authorization',
              headerPrefix: 'Bearer ',
              tokenName: 'auth_token',
              tokenGetter: (() => localStorage.getItem('auth_token')),
              globalHeaders: [{ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }],
              noJwtError: true,
              noTokenScheme: true
  })},
    AuthHttp
...
```

auth.service : 
// Check JWT token service

```
import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService  {

    loggedIn() {
    return tokenNotExpired();
    }

}
```

auth.guard.service :

```
// Check if the Token of the user is still valid
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AppState } from '../shared/interfaces';
import { SET_CURRENT_USER_PROFILE } from '../shared/state.actions';



import { Store } from '@ngrx/store'

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private auth: AuthService, private router: Router, private store: Store<AppState>) {}

  canActivate() {
    if(this.auth.loggedIn()) {
      return true;
    } else {
        console.log ('Token expired or not valid')
        localStorage.setItem('auth_token', '');
        localStorage.setItem('user', '');
        this.store.dispatch({ type: SET_CURRENT_USER_PROFILE, payload: null });
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

app.routing :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService]},
  { path: 'profile/:id', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService]},
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent}
];
```

EDIT: From the backend side everything is normally ok since the token is generated and stored in the localstorage after the user logs in.

Answer (score 2):

Its because of the property name, it assumes it is "token". So when you provide the property name as first parameter, it will work properly.

For example:

```js
tokenNotExpired('auth_token')
```

Some more information on the matter can be found here:
https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/issues/334

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION: So this is how i fixed it for everyone who may have the same problem, i used JWTHelper function isTokenExpired() instead of tokenNotExpired and I inversed the logic in the service and it worked not really sure why though

auth.service looks like that now :

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService  {

    private jwtHelper: JwtHelper = new JwtHelper();
    private token = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');

    isExpired() {
        return this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(this.token);
    }

}
```

and auth.guard.service canActivate():

```
  canActivate() {
    if (this.auth.isExpired()) {
        console.log (this.auth.isExpired());
        localStorage.setItem('auth_token', '');
        localStorage.setItem('user', '');
        this.store.dispatch({ type: SET_CURRENT_USER_PROFILE, payload: null });
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`localStorage.setI`tem('id-token',token);
```

the same token name used for saving token to local storage/session storage
can be pass as an argument to

```
return tokenNotExpired('id-token');
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the token as a parameter.

Change

```
loggedIn() {
  return tokenNotExpired();
}
```

to

```
loggedIn() {
  return tokenNotExpired('id_token');
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to explain why this works, and how the OP could have figured it out for themselves.

Comment: After a user successfully signs in, send the user's ID token to your server for more security. Then, on the server, verify the integrity of the ID token and use the user information contained in the token to establish a session or create a new account.

Comment: ITYM `'auth_token'`

Comment: yes, we can set the auth_token as authToken = localStorage.getItem('id_token');